# Wavesurfer + Soundcloud not work on Safari

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

My website use the plugin wavesurfer.js and API Soundcloud for streaming my music. I have a problem. The problem is on Safari browser, I have an error : Failed to load ressource: the serveur responded with a status of 403 (Forbiddon). I tried my code on another browser (ex : Firefox and Chrome). It work!

```
var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
 // init wavesurfer
wavesurfer.init({
  container : '#wf',
  waveColor : '#E0E0E0',
  progressColor : '#222',
  cursorColor : 'transparent',
  scrollParent : true,
});


$('#app').on('click','#spotlightplayer__play',function(event){
    $this = $(this);
    $parent = $this.parents('div.spotlightplayer');
    SC.stream('/tracks/' + SPOTLIGHT_PLAYER_CONFIGURE.track_id,function(stream){
       wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
            //wavesurfer.play();
            console.log("I'm ready");
        });
        wavesurfer.on('loading',function(){
            console.log('loading');
        });
        wavesurfer.on('error',function(){
            console.log('error');
        });
        wavesurfer.load(stream.url);

    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: you found a solution ?